# Can't deploy reports with workbench

Tags: metadata, migration-tool, workbench, deployment

I've retrieved some reports from my org, made changes to them and am trying to deploy them again through workbench. Everything went well until I try to deploy my zipped directory containing the package.xml and reports folder. Every single report fails with a '...not found in zipped directory' error.

I've tried every directory name and structure I could find a reference to online, with and without singlePackage on, nothing works. The folder and reportnames are correct, case and all.

Currently the structure looks like this:

```
src.zip
- src
    - package.xml
    - reports
        - ReportFolderDeveloperNameA
            - ReportName1.report
        - ReportFolderDeveloperNameB
            - ReportName2.report
```

package.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types> 
        <members>ReportFolderDeveloperNameA/ReportName1.report</members>  
        <members>ReportFolderDeveloperNameB/ReportName2.report</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

I have no clue what's going wrong, perhaps someone else will know.

Comment: You also need to include meta xml file for each of the report folder in `reports` folder .

Comment: for your example, it would be a file with the name `ReportFolderDeveloperNameA-meta.xml` inside `reports` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that all my issues were caused by not removing the '.report' part of the report name in the package.xml

Answer (score 0):

*for above case .report needs to be removed which is already mentioned*

I had the same issue but I read *Sales_Reports.reportFolder-meta.xml* file. where folder was having different types of read/write access. but those users were not available. So i commented  those lines and it worked like charm.

**example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <!-- <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>Manage</accessLevel>
    <sharedTo>xyz@abc.com</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>User</sharedToType>
    </folderShares> -->
    <name>Sales Dashboards Reports</name>
</ReportFolder>
```

commented few lines and which can be done manually later or create users with those names and then redeploy